# Syntax error when running Query: "syntax error at or near "\""

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, database-restore

I've generated a PostgreSQL script that I want to use to restore a database.  When I go to my backup server to try to restore, I get the error: `syntax error at or near "\"`.

It's getting stuck on the following characters `\.`

These appear like this:

```
COPY admin.roles (role_id, role_name, is_role_auto) from stdin;
\.
```

What's wrong with this statement?  Is there config I missed?  I'm on PostgreSQL 11.4 on Windows, the backup was taken with `pg_dump`, and I restore it using pgAdmin.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use pgAdmin to restore a "plain format" dump taken with `pg_dump`. It doesn't understand the `psql` syntax where `COPY` and its data are interleaved.

You will have to use `psql` to restore the dump:

```sh
psql -h server -p 5432 -U user -d database -f dumpfile.sql
```

Comment: MacOS tip: you will first need to install it via HomeBrew - `brew install libpq` && `brew link --force libpq`

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to know the specific error without seeing your backup and restore commands in their entirety, but if it helps, here is the boilerplate I use when I want to copy a table from production to a backup server:

```
$BIN/pg_dump -h production_server -p 5432 \
       --dbname=postgres \
       --superuser=postgres \
       --verbose \
       --format=c \
       --compress=9 \
       --table=admin.roles > backup.sql

$BIN/pg_restore \
      --host=backup_server \
      --port=5432 \
      --username=postgres \
      --dbname=postgres \
      --clean \
      --format=custom \
      backup.sql
```

The `format=c` (or `--format=custom`) makes the content completely unreadable, but on a plus side it also avoids any weird errors with delimiters and the like, and it also perfectly copies complex data structures like arrays and BLOBs.